# Implementing "Someone is typing…" functionality in angular chat application using socket.io

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io

I have ported the web version of the chat example into the angular 6.

Now I want to implement a feature that is such that when a User A starts typing then in realtime, user B should see a "User A is typing...." message. And when User A stops typing the message should disappear. Obviously, User A shouldn't see the message if he himself is typing.

Any better ideas about how can I achieve this? Any comments?

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Comment: Just fire up a event (for example ontyping ) during key-press   event and  on  blur fire up the  event (for example onmessage)  to send the  message text, also you could send the user id  along and in the client side and if the user id is same as current user then  don't show the typing...

Comment: also if you use `socket.broadcast.emit` instead of `io.sockets.emit` then  instead of emitting to all connected sockets it will emit to all connected socket except the one it is being called on. So in this case the socket referenced by socket will not receive the event. So you may be spared from sending the user id  is you use this method

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it emits an event on key press and when key press stopped emits a `nottyping` event after 500ms to stop showing thee typing message

var typing = false;

```
function typingstopped(){
  typing = false;
  socket.emit(notTyping);
}

function onKeyDown(){
  if(typing == false) {
    typing = true
    socket.emit(typing);
    time = setTimeout(typingstopped, 500);
  } else {
    clear(time);
    time = setTimeout(typingstopped, 500);
  }

}
```